# Open a new browser window, or set focus to an existing browser

Tags: apache-flex, browser, navigatetourl

I'm using code similar to the following:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/29/launching-new-browser-windows-from-flex/

I have a Flex app running in AIR, and when I click on a URL it opens a new tab in my existing browser.  In addition to this the focus doesn't set to the browser.  What this means is that I'm not aware of the URL opening in the browser unless I actually change focus from the app to the browser.

Is it possible to open a brand new spanking browser, or change focus to the browser so its really obvious to the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do in AIR / Flex to make this happen.  The behavior your seeing is due to operating system and browser settings.  In AIR, navigateToURL just passes the URLtot he OS which handles the URL based on defaults.

If memory serves me, my firefox install ued to open in a new tab by default, but there was some setting I used to make it always open in a new window.  Quick googling did not provide me the answer, though.